# General Settings > logo in the template

Tags: templating, config

I have uploaded a logo in the General Settings, which I understand changes the logo on the login page.

I was wondering if there was anyway to display this same logo in the site's template?

I know I can achieve this by hard-coding the same URL (but I presume if the logo is changed, this URL will change also.) My other solution is to add a field to a global set but that requires changing the logo in 2 places.

If this isn't possible, how can I retrieve the URL in a plugin? (I have a plugin with a few template helper methods.)

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

To fetch the logo:

```
{{ craft.rebrand.logo.url }}
```

To check if a logo is uploaded:

```
{% if craft.rebrand.isLogoUploaded %}
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. I decided to go with using an asset in the end, purely because I can then add alt-text and title using the control panel (and additional fields on the asset.)

Comment: Also I know this is only a feature for Client and above, but it would be useful if this was documented in the templating reference (http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/). I didn't see it anywhere so forgive me if it already is!

Comment: I haven't seen it mentioned anywhere. Found it be having a look the template login.html. By the way, you should mark this as accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

For version 3.x.x.

Check and get rebrand logo:

```
{% if craft.rebrand.isLogoUploaded() %}
    <img width="{{ craft.rebrand.getLogo().size[0] }}" height="{{ craft.rebrand.getLogo().size[1] }}" src="{{ craft.rebrand.getLogo().url }}">
{% else %}
    Not set.
{% endif %}
```

Check and get rebrand icon:

```
{% if craft.rebrand.isIconUploaded() %}
    <img width="{{ craft.rebrand.getIcon().size[0] }}" height="{{ craft.rebrand.getIcon().size[1] }}" src="{{ craft.rebrand.getIcon().url }}">
{% else %}
    Not set.
{% endif %}
```

Documentation for twig rebrand variable is here: https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-twig-variables-rebrand.html#public-methods